# iphone: Find other UI Elements inside UITableCell without using IBOutlet

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a bunch of custom UITableCells that I have built in interface builder.  These are then associated with their correct cell index and every looks great in my tableView.

Each cell has a few buttons, so rather than creating an outlet for each and every table cell button, is there a way to just "find" any UIButton types within the current cell?  I need to do this because I want to give it an IBAction so when you click on the button it does something.

I am just wanting to save code, rather than creating 20 or more IBOutlets.

Ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this way ..? I have my custom cell setup and I have a progressView on it, I am trying to get that progress view in my one of the viewControllers.

Comment: Yeah, this question is really old. But you need to give the buttons a tag, then use the `viewWithTag:` method to find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give each a unique tag in Interface Builder, you can find them with the `viewWithTag:` method of `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could iterate through the [`subviews`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/subviews) property in any `UIView`, then to check if it's specifically a `UIButton` you can use [`- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:). To differentiate between the `UIButton`s you can apply [tags](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag) to them or check other properties.

**EDIT**: By the way, why not just sub-class UITableViewCell, add your button(s) as IBOutlet properties, then when you want to access them you can just do myCell.someButton ? [Here](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/) is an article on how to sub-class UITableViewCell and use it in your UITableView.

If you do it this way, then everything will be organized. The UITableView will only worry about its UITableViewCells, and each UITableViewCell will worry about its individual UIButtons.

Comment: Ok, I tried: for (UIView *subview in cell.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
   NSLog(@"Found a button");
  }
    }

But that did not seem to find any buttons...

Comment: Try changing it to: UIView *subview in cell.contentView.subviews

Comment: That seems to no run the loop at all.